# Error when runing factories and seeders laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, laravel-migrations

I've created my first api in Laravel, and I'm having trouble generating the database from the migations. Every time I run `php artisan migrate` even after using `composer dump-autoload` and generating again the database it doesn't work. It gives me the error `Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use`.

I've tried to clear the cache with `composer clearcache` and `php artisan cache:clear` but the same error keeps appearing.

Why is that if the there isn't any migration table in the database ?

I've renamed the migrations and seeders files, so I had an easier time seeing what was created before and after and know it has the next structure. I won't be adding more table in the future. And below there are the code for the first table in case is for some help referencing the naming conventions or rules.

[image]

This is my user migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

My user model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

My user seeder:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PlatformSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\User::factory()->count(5)->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure that your migrations actually have unique names? Did you maybe copy/paste/duplicate one migration and forgot to change its name? Also, I don't think seeders/factories actually play a role in this

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @brombeer I'm using laravel version 8.83.27 .And the names of each table are unique, what seems strange is that the error ocurrs in the first table, when it shouldn't have to be any previous table to compare to. That's why I'm thinking that might be saving a register somewhere from before when I've been able to do it correctly the first time.

Comment: "_And the names of each table are unique_" Didn't mean the name of the tables but the name of the migration classes. Did you maybe search your project for "_CreateUsersTable_"?

Comment: @brombeer Sorry for the confusion. Yeah I've check them know and they appear just once

Answer (score 0):

Check your migrations table. It may already have a migration record with the same name. Try running `php artisan migrate:fresh` instead.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I ended up changing back the names files adding the date format that laravel uses and works again. So the lesson might be not messing with the format.
[image]

Comment: Seeders don't use the date format though, only migrations